# How to prevent `focusout` and redirect to another method

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have 3 element. when the user `focusout` on the last element, I am redirecting back to first element instead of focusing on browser elements. but it's not working. I am not able to prevent the `foucusout` how to handle this? How to stop before `focusout` and redirect to another method.

here is the snippet of my code :

```
 @HostListener('document:focusout', ['$event']) public DocFocus($event) {
$event.preventDefault();//not works
if (this.lastFocusElement && this.lastFocusElement === $event.target) {
  this.setFocus();//got to fist element 
  console.log('done', this.firstFocusElement);
}
```

}

on `focusout`, now my tab going to browser address bar.

Comment: seems `stopImmediatePropagation` may not be supported by Angular - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57852324/prevent-angular-hostlistener-propagation-to-parent-component

Comment: maybe `stopPropagation` is a viable option. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35274028/stop-mouse-event-propagation